# Changing the pixels of an image to the closest color from a given set of colors

Tags: image-processing

I don't have any coding experience and i am taking on a project that maybe a little ambitious considering my knowledge so i need some help..!

I am trying to convert the pixels of a couple of images of the earth globe to the closest color from a pallet of 16 different colors. The images are 160x160 pixels. My goal is to take those images and to convert them into the same 160x160 images but only containing pixels of the chosen colors.

I have the values of the 16 colors in hex format
- Black : #1D1D21
- Red : #B02E26
- Green : #5E7C16
- Brown : #835432
- Blue : #3C44AA
- Purple : #8932B8
- Cyan : #169C9C
- Light Gray : #9D9D97
- Gray : #474F52
- Pink : #F38BAA
- Lime : #80C71F
- Yellow : #FED83D
- Light Blue : #3AB3DA
- Magenta : #C74EBD
- Orange : #F9801D
- White : #F9FFFE

As an example, here is one of the images i have :
[earth view from the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf0FS.png)

If anyone could help me out and show me how i could accomplish this, it would be great!!
Thanks!

Comment: *Having no coding experience* is no excuse to get things the easy way, learning & trying to code it is the way to go. Show us what you can do and we will be glad to help in any problem that occurs.

Comment: My goal is not really to learn how to code or ''get things the easy way''. Im just seeking for some help to edit these pictures, which I realized wasn't really possible to do 1 pixel at a time in paint… That said, i am still trying to figure it out in the meantime, but first i need to install python and try stuff out so please be nice and bear with me here :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow! I would recommend you Python if you are a beginner to the coding world. Here is what I did for you using Python.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageColor

im = cv2.imread('earth.png') # read input image

def getClosestColor(pixel,color_set_rgb): # Get the closest color for the pixel
    closest_color = None
    cost_init = 10000
    pixel = np.array(pixel)
    for color in color_set_rgb:
        color = np.array(color)
        cost = np.sum((color - pixel)**2)
        if cost < cost_init:
            cost_init = cost
            closest_color = color
    return closest_color

def getClosestImage(im): # Get the closest image
    color_set = ['#1D1D21','#B02E26', '#5E7C16', '#835432', '#3C44AA', '#8932B8', '#169C9C', '#9D9D97', '#474F52', '#F38BAA',
     '#80C71F', '#FED83D','#3AB3DA' ,'#C74EBD' ,'#F9801D' ,'#F9FFFE'] # Given Colorset
    color_set_rgb= [ImageColor.getrgb(color) for color in color_set] # RGB Colorset

    height, width, channels = im.shape
    im_out = np.zeros((height,width,channels))

    for y in range(0, height):
        for x in range(0, width):
            closest_color = getClosestColor(im[y, x],color_set_rgb)
            im_out[y,x,:] = closest_color
    return im_out


im_out = getClosestImage(im)

plt.imshow(im_out.astype(np.uint8))
# plt.imsave('im_out.png',im_out/255)
plt.show()
```

[image: earth_out]

I hope you like it. Let me know if it helps! (For your information, you can mark this as the correct answer using the button on the left.)

Comment: That looks like its on the right track to what im looking for.. Is it possible to make a realistic looking output image? (like to end up with the ocean using the blue color for example). I am looking to use the images to build a 1 :1 scale of the earth using the pixels, that's why I chose to put it to 160 pixels wide. Looking at the results, i realize that even if the 16 colors are available, some are not really accurate to end up with a pixel ''realistic'' earth..

Comment: Looking at the script, i am thinking of some possible solutions with my limited knowledge of how it works. Maybe the technique to approximate the colors and transferring them to the closest one is flawed. Looking at the image, the blue ocean should be closest to the blue color normally even if it is a little darker or lighter.. shouldn't it..? Maybe by make the image a lot more bright, it will pickup the colors more closely to what the human eye can see… what do u think?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I enhanced the contrast of the input image, but it still gives a similar image. Let me briefly explain to you how the code works. The code iterates over every pixel in the image, and it calculates the distance of each pixel's color to every color in your color set in RGB values. The shortest distance (i.e. lowest cost) from this calculation means that the matched color is the most proper one. For example, the dark ocean parts have the RGB value (0,42,67). In the color set you provided, the blue color is (60, 68, 170) and the black one is (29, 29, 33).

Comment: So, by following the calculation `sum((color - pixel)**2)`, `sum(((29, 29, 33)- (0,42,67))**2)` returns a smaller cost than `sum(((60, 68, 170)- (0,42,67))**2)`, that's why, the pixel gets the black color. My suggestion is to find a better cost function or modify the input image. This task is a great excuse to learn coding btw :) Good luck with the rest, and let us know when you make it!